# Loop datatable using linq expression

Tags: c#, linq

I currently have a for loop to query rows on a datatable, but I was wondering how to write it as a linq expression instead?

```
for (int i = 0; i < repDT.Rows.Count; i += 1)
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: just clarification: you do not loop over database, you loop over results got from database.

Comment: It depends on what you have inside this `for` loop

Comment: can you post the code inside the `for` loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work:

```
var result = from DataRow row in repDT
             where row.property == (insert your condition)
             select row // (can be row, row.property etc)
```

You can also get results as a list like this:

```
var result = (from DataRow row in repDT
              where row.property == (insert your condition)
              select row).ToList(); // (can be row, row.property etc)
```

Comment: Add to follow up, the equivalent of the `for` loop for each example given in the answers above would be `foreach(var row in result) { .... }`, the first is evaluated at runtime, meaning the results are streamed from the expression to the foreach loop, and the second populates a list after getting all results. Both should work just fine, the first is usually preferred.